# How do I get the filename of an attachment before sending it in an email?

Tags: vba, outlook

I am using VBA for a prompt if I want to send to a specific user.
I also want it to show the filename that I am attaching.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim xPrompt As String
    Dim xOkOrCancel, Sty As Integer
    Dim recip As Recipient
    Dim att As Attachment

    On Error Resume Next
    
    For Each att In Item.Attachments
        Debug.Print att.FileName
    Next att

    xPrompt = "Do you want to continue sending the email to the following receipients with this file?"

    For Each recip In Item.Recipients
        xPrompt = xPrompt & vbNewLine & recip & att
    Next

    Sty = vbOKCancel + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton2
    xOkOrCancel = MsgBox(xPrompt, Sty)

    If xOkOrCancel <> vbOK Then
        Cancel = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course your code works incorrect, because you iterate attaches list, but you don't put result of every iteration to variable. At the end you have `att` variable with the last value of the list. Your code should look something like this:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim xPrompt As String
    Dim xOkOrCancel, Sty As Integer
    Dim recip As Recipient
    Dim att As Attachment
    Dim sFilesList As String
    Dim NeedToWarn As Boolean

    On Error Resume Next
    
    sFilesList = ""
    For Each att In Item.Attachments
        sFilesList = sFilesList & att.FileName & ", "
    Next att
    
    sFilesList = Left(sFilesList, Len(sFilesList) - 2) 'drop last comma
    
    NeedToWarn = False

    For Each recip In Item.Recipients
        If recip.Address = "somebody@domain.com" Then
            NeedToWarn = True
            
            xPrompt = "Do you want to continue sending the email to the following receipients with this file?"
            
            xPrompt = xPrompt & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & sFilesList
        End If
    Next
    
    If NeedToWarn Then
        Sty = vbOKCancel + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton2
        xOkOrCancel = MsgBox(xPrompt, Sty)

        If xOkOrCancel <> vbOK Then
    
            Cancel = True
    
        End If
    End If
    

End Sub
```

[Get attachments file names from emails vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37563275/get-attachments-file-names-from-emails-vba)

Comment: Tried this and it helped but on attaching multiple attachments it doesn't read it.

Comment: what you mean "it doesn't read it"? Can you show your entire code?

Comment: I just edited the code in the original post with the suggestion you gave me

Comment: @GHOSTR3V3RB I've changed my answer, check it